# fetch json data from url and update

Tags: android, json

I'm new here, give me a solution about json please.

I want to fetch json data to my app from url, and also want to update json data regularly without url change.
suppose, i want to show trending products in an activity, after one day i will change some products of that activity by changing data from json. after updating my json, url cant be change, cause doing update whole app regularly for changing url is not a good idea.

so, is this possible to update json data without changing url?

if yes, tell me please where can i store my json so that i can update t regularly.

or if you can provide any other better possible way to do this, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's why we use the database

Basically you need a database o structure your data, then you fetch data from the database using PHP which gives you a Json response

Since you are using Android Studio tag here is a good tutorial on how to fetch data from database using PHP , Json response [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yw7Lx9wqyGs)

First you gonna start with `LocalHost` , consider using `Xampp` , Then use `web hosting`

You create your `database` using `PhpMyAdmin` in LocalHost/phpMyAdmin and you read the `data` using `PHP` which return it in `Json` Format

Then migrate to `Web Hosting` , in `PhpMyAdmin` you can `export` your `Database` `from` your `LocalHost` and `Import` it in your `WebHost/PhpMyAdmin` , and you `upload` your `Php` files also